# eclipse import package

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to organize imports (org and com together, for example), without deleting unused ones ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Clean Up`, edit the profile and choose the `Unnecessary Code` tab.

Uncheck `Remove Unused Imports`

Comment: It was already unchecked. However preferences->java->editor->save actions has 'organize imports' unchecked too, but I'd like to check it in order to be able to organize imports by alphabetical order. But it has the side effect of removing unused imports. Any way around that?

Comment: Well, if you check `Organize Imports` and uncheck `Remove Unused Imports`, I would expect you'd get the behavior you want. If not, see if there's a bug report for your version of Eclipse.